# Pandas int/null issue : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

The below column 'Total' from my data frame has integers with extra .0 (1.0,2.0..) & Null values.
Before exporting data to csv, when below line of code executes it is throwing the error :  ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

```
df['Total'] = df['Total'].astype('Int64')
```

How to handle a column which has int & null values. At the same time if i remove above validation, Total output column coming as extra .0  (Ex: 11.0, 199.0, 33.0 etc). I want to export pure int/null to my csv.
Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there are some non numeric values, you can try [`to_numeric`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html) with `errors='coerce'` for convert this values to `NaN`s:

```
df['Total'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Total'], errors='coerce').astype('Int64')
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the reply : After above change, now i'm getting below error:         
    raise ValueError('Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to '
ValueError: Cannot convert non-finite values (NA or inf) to integer

Comment: @RK. - I guess problem is some floats values like `32.4`, how working `df['Total'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Total'], errors='coerce').round().astype('Int64')` for convert like `32.4` to `32` by round?

Comment: It has all int/null values only. integers like 32.0, 12.0, etc. No value after dot, we can trim it also.

Comment: @RK. - What is your pandas version? Because converting to integers is possible only in some 5 last version of pandas, `pandas 0.24+`